# Have a repeated image on top of everything

Tags: css, image, alignment, z-index, repeat

I'm having some trouble getting a specific look that I am after.

I have the basic Wordpress Twenty-Fifteen theme applied and I'm trying to get a 200px wide red bar to appear down the right hand side of the screen.

The bar is made of a 200x1px image that is repeated.

The problem is:

- A.) If I set this as a "Background-image" then the repeat works, but
  I cannot get the image on top.
- B.) If I set the image as an IMG
  inside of a DIV, then I can get the image on top, but not to repeat.

Can anyone help me combine these 2 into one result, repeated image-y and image on top?

You can see my site here: http://u64.ca/

Comment: An image of the *desired* result would be useful but I'm really thinking an image / background-image here is not the way to go.

Comment: What do you suggest then?

Comment: Until I know how it's supposed to look it's hard to comment further.

Comment: If you look at the link I provided, there is a "Background-Image" code there that renders a red bar down the side of the page. I simply want this red bar to be on top of the content boxes, as opposed to behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add it to your css.
This will affect everything the comes directly inside the #main tag.

```
#main > * {
margin-right: 200px;
}
```

Or you could apply a border right to the `.site-content` and lose the background iamge.

```
.site-content {
    border-right: 189px solid #db0f12;
}
```

Comment: Both of these simply shift the content over. I was hoping to have the edge of the red bar (about 20px worth of it) overlapping the contend boxes

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a pseudo-element something like:

```
main {
     position:relative;
}

main:after {
    content: "";
    width: 189px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #DB0F12;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, up until the footer. I'm going to play around with the code a touch more. But thanks!

Comment: You could use the same on the footer. At a guess, without looking through the site again, I'd guess that the footer is probably not in the `main` element.

Comment: Correction, main:after seems to put the bar within the blog post, not the whole page. (body:after seems to work, but doesn't go the length of the page)